# Why are some fields ignores despite clear mapping instructions?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have an index with strict mapping. There are some fields defined like this:

```
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "MMM D, YYYY @ HH:mm:ss"
      },
```

In the `_reindex` script, I convert some field values from the source numerical nanosecond values e.g. *1647846210839081472* into milliseconds so it can be recognized as a date, like this:

```
      if (ctx._source.created_at != null) {
        ctx._source.created_at = ctx._source.created_at / 1000000;
      }
```

This looks *mostly* OK in Kibana: they type is set to Date, they are shown correctly in the results, **except these fields can't be used for filters!**

Looking at the document JSON, I notice this block on each:

```
  "_ignored": [
    "created_at",
    "updated_at",
    ***OTHER SIMILAR DATE FIELDS**
  ],
```

How can I make ES or Kibana treat those fields as full members of the club?

Comment: So `created_at` is a `long` in the source index but a `date` in the target index and your reindex script just does a division? You probably need to remove the `format` from your mapping as your dates are not formatted that way

Comment: Thanks, I'll try without the format option.

Comment: ✅ I did remove the `"format": "MMM D, YYYY @ HH:mm:ss"` from the mapping and everything worked well than. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured out, you should create an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Val's suggestion, I figured ES and Kibana were confused by the `"format": "MMM D, YYYY @ HH:mm:ss"` in the mapping, which was not matching the milliseconds coming from the `_script`.

My expectation was that ES would interpret the `date` automatically and use the format *for display.* I was wrong. After removing the `format` from the mapping, ES and Kibana were able to work with the data as is.

Answer (score 1):

The field **was malformed** (due to the strict mapping) and **ignore_malformed is set to true** that's why it was ignored.

I'm thinking of two solutions:

1- update your mapping in order to accept the numerical nanosecond values.

you can use  [date_nanos](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date_nanos.html) type to avoid converting your field and accept the origin value).

2- set ignore_malformed to false when creating your index: not recommended, check the documentation and explanation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html#ignore-malformed).

Comment: I'm already saving the values as milliseconds. I believe it has to do with the format, I'll try again.